# Discriminatively trained supervised part of speech tagging

Tags: nlp, svm, part-of-speech, pos-tagger

I have to implement a Discriminatively trained supervised part of speech tagger, and I have been looking at a couple of techniques including Maximum likelihood, perceptron and the large margin (SVM). Finally after reading through some experimental results quoted in a couple of research papers i have come down to using SVMs for it. I have been studying it for some time and a couple of things in theory seem a little confusing.
Can someone please point me to some relevant reading material to a practical implementation or just more clarification on how to implement it using Viterbi Algorithm.

P.S. : I am not asking for the solution, but just need some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, to read some classic papers.

- the well-known trigram based approach, [TnT](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/980000/974178/p224-brants.pdf?ip=193.225.109.136&acc=OPEN&CFID=143714410&CFTOKEN=53138945&__acm__=1353329334_8766bcfd0694ca7c2edc0cb38b267e91).
- the famous [maximum entropy approach by Ratnaparkhi](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/W/W96/W96-0213.pdf) and his [dissertation](http://www.ai.mit.edu/courses/6.891-nlp/READINGS/adwait.pdf):

And a step-by-step construction [paper](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~gmalecha/pub/max-ent-pos.pdf) using Maxent in Python NLTK:

You could also study some open source software, such as [Apache OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/), [Python NLTK](http://nltk.org) or my own implementation [PurePos](https://github.com/ppke-nlpg/purepos)

For using SVM, you could look around [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_hmm.html) and [here](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~nlp/SVMTool/#).